# Preventing data regression during merge via apex triggers

Tags: apex, trigger

We have a custom picklist field on Contact that we need to prevent from regressing. For example, the values are First, Second, Third, Fourth and we don't want to allow a change from Third to, say, First.  We were able to control this for Contact updates using some simple apex triggers.

The situation that we can not resolve is when a merge operation is executed.  Our desired result is the same - regardless of the user's selection we will not regress the picklist value.  Based on the["Triggers and Merge Statements"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm) documentation from Salesforce we have determined that we can interrogate Contacts in the afterDelete trigger to determine if they have MasterRecordId set and then take action to determine the *real* winning value for the picklist field in question.

But then what do we do with this information? It doesn't persist outside of the trigger context so how can we use this new list of the *real* winning values in the subsquent BeforeUpdate trigger?  Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trigger that would work (using Lead Source as an example):

```
trigger PreventRegression on Contact (before update) {
    for(Contact record: [SELECT Id, LeadSource, MasterRecordId FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE and MasterRecordId IN :Trigger.new ALL ROWS]) {
        if(Trigger.newMap.get(record.MasterRecordId).LeadSource < record.LeadSource) {
            Trigger.newMap.get(record.MasterRecordId).LeadSource = record.LeadSource;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use a static variable to save a query, if you wanted to, but that is a little more complex. The static variable method works because the before/after delete triggers and before/after update triggers run in the same context, allowing them to share static variables.

Answer (score 0):

the merge command will run the before delete trigger on all items to be deleted, including the one that will be set with the masterrecordid in the after delete trigger. <s>In your before delete, update the value of your pick list on all records to the highest value, then, regardless of which is chosen as winner, it has the proper value.</s>

nb: never tried the above. Should work, I think.

Turns out that doesn't work. sorry for the noise.

Comment: Don't worry, you were closer than you realize.