# Bypass custom Contact trigger on a Contact merge

Tags: trigger, contact, merge

I have some custom beforeUpdate trigger code on the Contact object that I want to bypass if the update is the result of a merge. Is there something similar to the MasterRecordId used on the losing Contact that I can check to know that this is the winning Contact of a merge?

Comment: This may help - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/21129/12753

Comment: Bennie, 
That link did provide a way to determine that the contact was the winning contact. So when I did the merge I was able to use it in the before trigger to determine that there was alosing contact with that masterRecordId. However I then tried a regular update of the Contact and it still found that deleted record so I'm back to the same issue. How do I know when this before Update is the result of a merge or just someone doing an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking there can be a possible way.  How about you capture all the MasterRecordId in a Set and then use this Set to check if the record in context is being updated due to a merge:

```
 Set<Id> MasterIds = new Set<Id>(); 
  if(trigger.isDelete && trigger.isAfter){
   for(Account a : trigger.old){
  if(a.MasterRecordId != null){
   MasterIds.add(a.MasterRecordId);
 }
}

if(trigger.isUpdate){
 for(Account a : trigger.new){
   if(MasterIds.contains(a.Id){
      //Your logic. It means this record is being updated due to merge.
  }
 }
```

}

Let me know if it works.

Comment: That was the trick. I created a static variable for my trigger class and set the MasterIds during the 'after delete' trigger on the losing records. I am then able to reference those id's in the 'before update' trigger in the winning record.  Thank you

Comment: glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

MasterRecordId field in trigger.old is actually the ID of the winning record. 
Can you please elaborate if I didn't answer exactly.

Comment: The last step of the merge is to fire off the update of the winning Contact. Do you mean in the beforeUpdate trigger of that Contact the MasterRecordId in trigger.old will let me know this is the winning Contact?

Comment: Yes i believe so

Comment: I tried it but the MasterRecordId is null in trigger.old. It is my understanding that MasterRecordId is only set on the losing Contact.

Comment: Wait i ll check once

Comment: This may help you.. Please check out the link for the sequence of operations. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm

Answer (score 0):

I created two test account just to check the effect of merge operation and also created a trigger like below. Just after the merge operation was completed, I opened the debug log and observed the folowing:

1. First of all, "before delete" triggers are called due to records being deleted as a result of merge operation. MasterRecordId=null in this case because this account is getting deleted.
2. Then "after delete" trigger is called for the deleted records. MasterRecordId is not null. It's 0019000001IgQg4AAF, which is the Id of the winning record.
3. Then "before update" trigger for winning record is fired.MasterRecordId is null which is OK, because it's an update operation.
4. Then "after update" trigger for the same winning record is fired.MasterRecordId is null which is OK, because it's an update operation.

To summarize - You can access MasterRecordId NOT EQUAL to null only in "after delete" triggers. This field will contain the Id of the winning record.

I hope this clears all your doubt.

TRIGGER:
[image]

Comment: You are missing my question. In Step 3 of you post when that before update fires is there a way to determine if this update is the result of a merge or someone making an update in general.